# I use sphinx to build pdf ,How to generate automatic indices

Tags: pdf, latex, python-sphinx

sphinx can general index as well as a language-specific module indices,But when I use sphinx generate pdf ,I can not find the automatic indicies，what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the build twice?

Latex may get the indexes only right after the second build. During the first run, the document with table of content and indices is generated, during the second build that information is used in the latex file.

Comment: @liminkai: If you have comments to my answer, please do not edit my post but provide a comment.

Answer (score 0):

What is in your index.rst file?

In the index.rst file, it is necessary to insert "modules" manually in order for the PDF to work correctly (assuming your build process creates modules.rst in same folders as index.rst).  Otherwise, the PDF output just includes nothing.